# Django - Timeuntil Tag output abbreviation

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I'm using django timeuntil template tag and the output is something like `8 hours, 15 minutes`. Does anyone have any idea how I can make the output to be like `8 Hr, 15 Min` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to  [timesince from django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py):

```
chunks = (
    (60 * 60 * 24 * 365, ungettext_lazy('%d year', '%d years')),
    (60 * 60 * 24 * 30, ungettext_lazy('%d month', '%d months')),
    (60 * 60 * 24 * 7, ungettext_lazy('%d week', '%d weeks')),
    (60 * 60 * 24, ungettext_lazy('%d day', '%d days')),
    (60 * 60, ungettext_lazy('%d hour', '%d hours')),
    (60, ungettext_lazy('%d minute', '%d minutes'))
)
```

The fast and easy way to change it is [wrote your custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to change `hours` by `Hr`:

```
def my_time_abbr(value): 
    return value.replace( 'hours', 'Hr').replace('minutes','Min')
```

In your template:

```
{{ somedata | timeuntil | my_time_abbr }}
```

You can also rewrite `timesince` filter from scratch (copy paste from django timesince) if you are working in Internationalization mode.