# Django display time (hours and/or minutes)

Tags: django

How do I display the hours and/or minutes?

code (html):

```
<td>{{ tool.dueDate | timeuntil }}</td>
```

It only displays:

```
6 days
```

I was hoping for:
`6 days 23 hours 10 minutes` or `6 days 23 hours`. Either of those are fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332302/django-timeuntil-tag-output-abbreviation

Comment: @alecxe Thank you, it works. I ran runserver again, and it was able to appear the hours. Thanks!